# Can't delete files in the Trash in a SD card. Files are both there and not there

Tags: trash, sd-card

I wanted to delete some files on an SD card but then emptying the trash would take too long so I just canceled it and went with terminal to wipe it manually with `rm -rf`

But then there are some directories that have some files that show up like they're there, but then when trying to delete or list them I get *No such file or directory*. Trying to delete the directory with `rm -rf` gets *Directory not empty*.

Disk Utility won't fix it.
I'd like not to have to format the SD card if possible.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rm after cd-ing to /Volumes/SD16GB/.Trashes (assuming you don't need anything in the trash)?

Comment: @NoahL Yes, I did. Didn't work.